# nginx redirect all images to new domain

Tags: redirect, nginx

I had links to my images something like it:

mydomen.com/upload/iblock/f88/f887c7bc3229b93a0a0f7c248d3aefb5.jpg

regex is something like it:
mydomen.com/upload/(catalog|iblock|medialibrary|partners|resize_cache|rk|sale|uf)/*/.(jpg|png|jpeg)

and now i thansfered all my images to storage and now my images have these urls:
images.mydomen.com/iblock/f88/f887c7bc3229b93a0a0f7c248d3aefb5.jpg

so, from mydomen.com i move to images.mydomen.com and removed /upload/

can anyone helps me to redirect all requests images to new domain via nginx location??

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^/upload((catalog|iblock|medialibrary|partners|resize_cache|rk|sale|uf)/.*\.(jpg|png|jpeg))$ https://images.example.com$1 permanent;`

Comment: this?   




location ^/upload((catalog|iblock|medialibrary|partners|resize_cache|rk|sale|uf)/.*\.(jpg|png|jpeg))$ {
                rewrite https://images.example.com$1 permanent;
        }

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remove the `/upload/` prefix from the original URI using a *regular expression* and capturing the remainder. You can use either the `rewrite` or `location` directives.

For example:

```
rewrite ^/upload((catalog|iblock|medialibrary|partners|resize_cache|rk|sale|uf)/.*\.(jpg|png|jpeg))$ https://images.example.com$1 permanent;
```

Or using a `location` block:

```
location ~* ^/upload((catalog|iblock|medialibrary|partners|resize_cache|rk|sale|uf)/.*\.(jpg|png|jpeg))$ {
    return 301 https://images.example.com$1;
}
```

The *regular expression* `location` blocks are evaluated in order, so its position within the configuration file may be significant. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.